# Can one protect the Mobile Safari cache from physical access?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, wkwebview, browser-cache

If someone gains access to a physical device [one should assume the attacker has access to all data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405572/44292) that is unencrypted. In my app, the data I am concerned with protecting is the Mobile Safari cache, more specifically the images that are being cached by my app. Right now, caching is disabled, but this has quite the impact on perceived performance, and I am itching to enable caching, but as these images are of a highly sensitive nature, I need to be sure I can protect any cached images from snooping. Encrypting the files has been proposed, but that presents new problems:

- can you specify an encrypted location to Mobile Safari to use as the storage location (probably not)?
- is the default location used by Safari encrypted in some way?

If there are ways to protect it while keeping UX high, do let me know.

Comment: All iOS storage is encrypted, protected by the user's passcode/biometrics. If the attacker can obtain or compromise the passcode protection then the file system is unlocked. If not then the file system is secure. Modern iOS devices are generally well protected against even USB level attack.  Only you (or your organisation) can assess risk; the sort of attack you are describing is a motivated, targeted attack probably by a state actor, not what you would expect on a device that was merely lost/stolen. Is that the sort of attack you expect?

Comment: @Paulw11 Not at all. But there have been recent attacks against hospital infrastructure in Finland where patients have been blackmailed, so there are private interests as well that are interested in getting sensitive information on individuals. Ref https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/26/tens-of-thousands-psychotherapy-records-hacked-in-finland

Comment: @Paulw11 Your comment more or less contains the information I want, but it lacks credible background information/links to Apple. If you would mind adding that I would like to award you the accepted answer.

Comment: Apple publishes a comprehensive [platform security guide](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/welcome/1/web) .  The [pdf version](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1902/en_US/apple-platform-security-guide.pdf) is quite in-depth